# nth-child zebra striping divs in CSS3: any way to reset per parent container?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I have a form containing fieldsets. The fieldsets contain divs, grouping related form items (label + input).

It looks like this:

```
<fieldset> 
    <div class="formitem">
        <label for="age">
            age
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="[age]">
    </div>
    <div class="formitem">
        <label for="birthday">
            birthday
        </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="[birthday]">
    </div>
    <div class="formitem">
        <label for="size">
            size
        </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="[size]">
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I am using this CSS to add a darker green stripe to every odd (1st, 3rd etc) div .formitem:

```
fieldset .formitem:nth-child(odd) {
     background: #a7cc87;
}
```

But this adds the background colour to every odd-numbered .formitem through the entire document, ignoring the separated fieldsets.

What I would want is that the odd/even count begins again for each fieldset, so that if fieldset 1 ends on an odd number, the first item in fieldset 2 will still get the odd style.

Is there any way to achieve this with CSS, or do I need to use JQuery?

Comment: It seems to work for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cdssx/ Am I missing something?

Comment: A quick work-around would be to add different classes to the div's in separate feildsets and then call your css for each separate fieldset.

Comment: Nope, I must be missing something- thanks for the JSFiddle, will investigate to see what I've done wrong.